# WNDA3100v2 – N600 WiFi USB Adapter (Netgear USB)

Tags: wireless, broadcom, adapter, netgear

I bought this adapter not too long ago since my computer don't own a network card yet. Ran the CD and tried to install with Wine, but I just got an error saying it couldn't continue the process. I have searched a little around about ndiswrapper etc etc, but I am completely new to Ubuntu so what the heck even is this.

Basically right now I am running the netgear on another laptop, connected with a bridge to the ethernet I am using between the two devices. I'd rather not keep a laptop running by all times if I have to use my desktop computer. When running the lsusb command in the terminal, it shows it's connected even though the usb isn't glowing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The duplicate is a v2; the subject v3 is a different chipset.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, retracted accordingly.